# How to remove the label error using jquery when mouseover on it?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove the label error using jquery when mouse over on it. am using new version of jquery (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js). Its working for a particular div and not working for label.error method.

Html

```
 <div  class="old">New Para Div</div>
 <div  class="old">New Para Div</div>
 <div class="old">New Para Div</div>
 <div class="old">New Para Div</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(".old").on("mouseover",function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

the above coding is working. but this one is not working.

```
$("label.error").on("mouseover",function(){
     $(this).remove();
     });
```

Can anyone help me, please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be because the `error` labels are created dynamically

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "label.error", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```